# Typical architecture and query for RDBMS and triple

Tags: marklogic

Is there a reference architecture and query sample for RDBMS and triples?

With two RDBs with different schemas, we expect MarkLogic can use triples which map both schema and enable DBs-wide query such as

SELECT dba.address 
WHERE dba.address IN dbb.address;

where dba.address and dbb.address are different column but we have a domain ontology that dba.address and dbb.address are nearly the same.